# Inserir valor no input text mais proximo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

boa tarde galera, estou com um problema em meu jquery
é o seguinte, terei varios formularios em uma pagina... 
Onde ao digitar em cada campo "placa" o meu jquery insere um valor no próximo campo concessionaria, do mesmo formulario.

tentei usar o closest("form").find("#concessionaria")
porém não obtive sucesso

aqui tem um link do jsfiddle tentando representar o que quero que aconteça

https://jsfiddle.net/wrh2pszo/1/

Comment: O teu jsFiddle funciona, se adicionares jQuery... https://jsfiddle.net/wrh2pszo/3/

Comment: boa noite sergio, e se caso eu queira adicionar valores distintos (por ex. o valor da placa) para cada "concessionaria", como eu faria?

Comment: Queres usar o valor que estás a inserir? ou tens dados específicos para cada input?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas talvez resolva seu problema!
https://jsfiddle.net/wrh2pszo/8/

```
<form>
        <label for="placa">Placa:</label>
        <input type="text" class="placa">

        <label for="concessionaria">Concessionaria:</label>
        <input type="text" name="concessionaria" id="concessionaria">
</form>
<form>
        <label for="placa">Placa:</label>
        <input type="text" class="placa">

        <label for="concessionaria">Concessionaria:</label>
        <input type="text" name="concessionaria" id="concessionaria">
</form>
<form>
        <label for="placa">Placa:</label>
        <input type="text" class="placa">

        <label for="concessionaria">Concessionaria:</label>
        <input type="text" name="concessionaria" id="concessionaria">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(".placa").on('input', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('#concessionaria').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Troque o script para:

```
$(".placa").on('input', function () {
            $(this).parent().find("input[name$='concessionaria']").val($(this).val());
        });
```